# Load data from a text file to R

Tags: r

I have data in text format whose structure is as follows:

```
ATCTTTGAT*TTAGGGGGAAAAATTCTACGC*TTACTGGACTATGCT
.........T.....,,,,,,,,,.......T,,,,,,.........
......A..*............,,,,,,,,.A........T......
    ....*..................,,,T...............
     ...*.....................*...........
           ...................*.....
```

I have been trying to import it into R using the read.table() command but when I do the output has an altered structure like this:

```
                                               V1
1 ATCTTTGAT*TTAGGGGGAAAAATTCTACGC*TTACTGGACTATGCT
2 .........T.....,,,,,,,,,.......T,,,,,,.........
3 ......A..*............,,,,,,,,.A........T......
4      ....*..................,,,T...............
5           ...*.....................*...........
6                       ...................*.....
```

For some reason, R is shifting the rows with lesser number of characters to the right. How can I load my data into R without altering the data structure present in the original text file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
read.table(file, sep = "\n")
```

result:

```
                                               V1
1 ATCTTTGAT*TTAGGGGGAAAAATTCTACGC*TTACTGGACTATGCT
2 .........T.....,,,,,,,,,.......T,,,,,,.........
3 ......A..*............,,,,,,,,.A........T......
4     ....*..................,,,T............... 
5      ...*.....................*...........     
6            ...................*.....
```

Comment: It's not working for me, my result is the same as I was getting before. Was the file you loaded stored as .txt format?

Comment: I created a *.txt file and saved your text inside. Then I used read.table() with argument sep = "\n" and it worked.
Your file is stored also as *.txt file?

Comment: yes it is stored as a *.txt file. I am trying like this: read.table("file.txt",sep="\n")